# Supervisor cannot start Gunicorn: ENOENT

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, gunicorn, supervisord

I have deployed Django using gunicorn and nginx. The django project is located in a virtual environment. Everything is working perfectly when I run -

> gunicorn mydjangoproject.wsgi -c gunicorn_config.py

I am running the above command inside my Django project folder containing manage.py with the virtual environment active.

However now i want to close the server terminal and want gunicorn to run automatically. For this I am using Supervisor. I have installed supervisor using apt-get and created a gunicorn.conf file in supervisor's conf.d.

But when I run supervisorctl start gunicorn I am getting a fatal error-
    gunicorn: ERROR (abnormal termination)

So checked the log file and it says-

supervisor:couldn't exec root/ervirtualenvpy2/bin/gunicorn: ENOENT
child process was not spawned

My configuration file for supervisor's gunicorn.conf looks like this-

```
[program:gunicorn]
command = root/ervirtualenvpy2/bin/gunicorn myproject.wsgi -c     root/path/to/the/gunicorn_conf.py/file
directory = root/ervirtualenvpy2/path/to/myproject/
user=root
autorestart=true
```

Comment: ENOENT mean the file not found. Check you filepath and supervisord access right.

Comment: Why are you so keen to use supervisor rather than upstart or systemd which is included in your system already?

Comment: Well, I am using supervisor because in future I want to add celery, rabbitmq and memcached to my project and I am really new to all this server setup and deployment so I don't know much about upstart and systemd. I am relying on the information I found when I started studying about this setup and I first encountered supervisor.

Comment: Same Issue for me.

Comment: One possible scenario: `you renamed the venv directory`. It happened to me and it was a headache. Everything was well configured on Supervisor, but for a lack of attention, I renamed the venv folder, because I was changing the name of my application, and for one second, I thought that there wouldn't be any problem on renaming the venv folder. DON'T DO THAT. Create a new one instead an update the references on Supervisor or whichever app/service that has interaction with your application.

Answer (score 2):

Going by what you said and your config everything seems right except that you have specified relative path rather than absolute path:

see gunicorn [docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#supervisor)

Instead it should be:

```
[program:gunicorn]
command = /root/ervirtualenvpy2/bin/gunicorn myproject.wsgi -c /root/path/to/the/gunicorn_conf.py/file
directory = /root/ervirtualenvpy2/path/to/myproject
user=root
autorestart=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Also Check your gunicorn file path in env/bin/gunicorn file

In my case, I changed my `env` directory to another place, so please be sure with that
Wrong path: `#!/home/ubuntu/nikhil_project/env/bin/python`
Correct path: `#!/home/ubuntu/env/bin/python`